# Braintree Sandbox Account and Paypal integration

Tags: javascript, paypal, asp.net-mvc-5, braintree

After creating a Sandbox Account with Braintree I tried to implement payment with Paypal, using Braintree dropin ui. I am using Java SDK on the client side with .NET at server side. I followed steps given on site and it generates a form with paypal button, on click it opens up a PayPal pop up window in which I enter my account details. After which it asks to agree on some terms. After clicking Agree it says :

`"Sorry we cannot connect to PayPal. Please try again in a few minutes. Try Again"`

How can I resolve this issue.

Comment: There could be a host of reasons for this error and without any information about your integration there isn't much to go on. I recommend you contact [Braintree support](https://support.braintreepayments.com) with more information about your account to figure out why you're getting this error.

Answer (score 1):

Have you verify PayPal is a valid payment method in your sandbox account? The problem could be coming from the processor that did not set up properly on your sandbox account. You can check that by logging to your sandbox account and click on Settings->Processing. Here, you'll see a list of accepted payment methods next to the Merchant Account section.If PayPal is listed as one of the processor, it should appear in Accepted Payment Methods.

[image]

Comment: What should be done if Paypal is not shown in the Accepted Payment Methods List ?

Comment: @azlankasim Can you please tell us how to add paypal in accepted payment methods list ?